# RactiveJS bind multiple objects to template

Tags: javascript, data-binding, ractivejs

Is it possible to bind more than one data object to a template? I find the single object philosophy a bit resistant to scalability.
How can I add more observant data objects to a template without modifying the one already attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you instanciate the ractive instance you could do something like this.

```
var r = new Ractive({data : {Object1:{},
                             Object2:{} } });
```

Then you can attached as many objects as you want.

Then you can scope this in your templates by doing

```
{{#Object1}}
<div>{{Prop1}}
{{/Obj1}}

{{#Object2}}
<div>{{PropForObject2}}
{{/Obj2}}
```